# How can I allow Apache to read the status of my git repo?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, git

My website reports on the Git status (current commit and branch, mostly, and also `git ls-files --modified` to show any files which have been modified directly on the server) so I can check at a glance whether it's up to date. This used to work, but the latest Git does not allow these things to be read by a user which does not own the repo.

The command `git config --global --add safe.directory {$dir}` works in principle, but does *not* work for `www-data`, because it has no `$HOME`, so there's nowhere for the `.gitconfig` file to be created. The response is `fatal: $HOME not set`.

Is there any straightforward way to allow Apache to read a few facts about the Git repo? This is all PHP code using `exec()` to run commands such as `git branch --show-current` and `git log -1 --pretty=%H`, among others.

Answer (score 0):

You can set environment variables. So, setting `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL` to point to your modified configuration should solve the "no-$home problem".

Using `-c key=value`, you can set configuration options for every `git` call separately, which should allow you to work like you want to, as well.

However, hm. You're running your PHP as a user which has read privileges on private files, it seems! Either, you're running a shared repository as a dedicated user, in which case it'd seem more appropriate to run your PHP interpreter as that user. Or, you give your apache-run PHP interpreter read access to your private files. That's basically not OK for anything public – having a wrapper script that really only does one job (namely, calling git with exactly the right options and maybe a branch name passed as argument) that you add to your /etc/sudoers so that your PHP can sudo that (and only that) as the repo-owning user, but not otherwise read data, does seem wiser.

---

I'd like to add that, if you're exposing this publicly,

> This is all PHP code using `exec()` to run commands such as `git branch --show-current` and `git log -1 --pretty=%H`

does sound like a lot of potential for remote code execution. You'd probably be better off using a library that does that for you instead!

Comment: The commands are hard-coded, not user input. And that section of code is never run unless you're (a) on an unusual page on the site, and (b) logged in as an administrator. I know that `exec()` is not recommended, but I think this is safe enough.